# How to fix text overlapping with setInterval and fillStyle?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am very new to JavaScript and have very little knowledge about why certain symbols/characters act the why they do. So if you don't mind explaining a bit how the fix helped my code that would be a huge boost in my understanding. Thanks!

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>

<script>

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");


var interval = setInterval(function()
{

var time= new Date()

  ctx.font="30px Verdana";
// Create gradient
  var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,c.width,0);
  gradient.addColorStop("0","green");
  gradient.addColorStop("0.5","blue");
  gradient.addColorStop("1.0","green");
// Fill with gradient
  ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
  ctx.fillText(time,10,90);



},10)

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the canvas prior to drawing the text. Add the following code to the beginning of your setInterval function:

`ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);`